# connect kafka broker to remote zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have one machine where kafka it to be ran and another machine where zookeeper is running.
How to connect kafka broker (from one machine) to zookeeper (to another machine) ?

I have tried to open **2181** port for zookeeper and **9092** for kafka broken and also modified *server.properties* config file like that:

`advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://3.8.97.85:9092`

`zookeeper.connect=3.10.180.209:2181`

where **3.8.97.85** is kafka's IP address, and **3.10.180.209** - zookeeper IP, but get error:
"ZooKeeperClientTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING"

Answer (score 0):

Latest Kafka no longer requires Zookeeper...

What you've done is correct. Perhaps there's another networking issue, such as at the router since `3.x.x.x` is not a reserved private network space.

Debug your network connectivity using tools like netcat or telnet

Comment: no, 3.x.x.x is public IP. my kafka and zookeeper are different machines with different networks. I want to connect with public IPs.

Comment: You should use internal network IPs to connect Kafka and Zookeeper rather than public ones. You should also check that the Zookeeper server isn't only bound to listen on its localhost / network, and that its firewall even allows remote connections... Like I said, what you've done is correct. This is no longer a Kafka issue, but rather something to debug in your own network / OS

Comment: if I use internal network how I can achieve building kafka cluster among different regions?

Comment: That's what Kafka advertised listeners are for. I was referring only to  kafka and zookeeper connectivity